# Trying to write a delimited file using LINQ and XML, but can't make it work with strings

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to get information from IMDB on a list of about 1500 movies. I found a website to get the data from in an XML file but I'm having trouble getting the data out. I wanted to write this into a delimited file so I can import this entire thing in access so I can have a comprehensive imdb database of these movies. this is my code thus far.

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Text

    Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click

    Dim bug As String = ""
    Dim genre As String = ""
    Dim MoviesList() As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim amirunning As Boolean = True
    Dim rating As String = ""
    Dim year As String
    Dim rated As String
    Dim directors As String
    Dim writers As String
    Dim actors As String
    Dim plot As String



    MoviesList = {1500 movies in here}

    Do While counter < MoviesList.Length And counter <= 0

        Label1.Text = MoviesList(counter)

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=" & MoviesList(counter) & "&type=xml")

        Dim BookXDocument = XDocument.Load("http://deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=" & MoviesList(counter) & "&type=xml")
        Dim myquery = From movie In BookXDocument.<movie>
        Select movie...<genres>.Value


        Dim myquery2 = From movie In BookXDocument.<movie>
        Select movie...<languages>.Value


        textbox1.text = myquery



        counter = counter + 1
    Loop

End Sub


End Class
```

I cant figure out how the hell to get the myquery and myquery2 values to be used as a string!

I get the following error on line

```
    textbox1.text = myquery
```

it comes back as "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.String'."

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method. If you want these as delimited with `,`, for example, do something like this (my apologies if VB.NET syntax is bad, not practiced):

```
Dim movieList = String.Join( _
    ", ", _
    From movie In BookXDocument.<movie> Select movie...<genres>.Value)
Dim languageList = String.Join( _
    ", ", _
    From movie In BookXDocument.<movie> Select movie...<languages>.Value)
```

Comment: Well once I can get all these values working as a string I can do that, however the
        textbox.text = myquery

 part throws an exception of "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: Use `String.Join` to convert your queries to strings. Then assign to your textbox. To put it another way, `textbox1.text = String.Join(", ", myquery)`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `myQuery` contains the query expression, not the result. In LINQ, you have to run the query after configuring it.

There are many ways to run.

- For Each over the data

  Call the .ToARrya(), .ToList() or ToDictionary() methods.

  textbox1.Text = myQuery.ToArray();

Looks like you are working with XML, so you many need to use some Linq To XML helpers to drill down into the XML data to get your strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the xml right into your datatable, using the ReadXML method of the table.